# Como posso gravar uma matriz num arquivo .txt em Java da mesma forma que aparece no console?

Tags: java, arquivo, matriz

Eu fiz um código que gera uma matriz quadrada N x N com números aleatórios. Até aí ok. Fiz um método pra poder gravar essa matriz num arquivo `.txt`, só que a matriz simplesmente sai com valores aleatórios, mesmo eu fazendo a conversão de toda estrutura da matriz de `int` para `String`.

Segue a classe principal:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.IOException;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("De o valor para dimensão de uma matriz quadrada: ");
    int N = in.nextInt();
    int [][] matrix1 = new int[N][N];
    //double [][] matriz2 = new double[N][N];
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {     
        for (int j = 0 ; j < N ; j++) {
            Integer r = rand.nextInt()% 1000; 
            matrix1[i][j] = Math.abs(r);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("A matriz quadrada gerada de tamanho " + N + " foi:");
    printMatrix graph = new printMatrix();
    graph.printGraph(matrix1, N);
    graph.matrixToFile(matrix1);
}
```

Daí fiz uma classe com dois métodos:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class printMatrix {
    public void printGraph(int[][] array, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
            System.out.print("[");   
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("]");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");   
    }

    public void matrixToFile(int[][] array) throws IOException {
        FileWriter arqMatrix = new FileWriter("Matriz 1.txt");
        PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arqMatrix);
        gravarArq.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        arqMatrix.close();
        System.out.println("Arquivo 'Matriz 1.txt' no mesmo local do projeto.\n");
    }
}
```

Até aí também tudo bem. O problema é quando eu faço essa função "`gravarArq.println(Arrays.toString(array));`". Ele fica com caracteres aleatorios, como se fosse em bytes, como: `[[I@28d93b30`, `[I@1b6d3586`, `[I@4554617c]` (no caso de colocar 3, ele sempre gera isso dependendo de como for o "N".

Se você colocar um `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));` você gera esses valores aleatorios no proprio console, ou colocar um `+ "teste"` no final de `gravarArq.println(Arrays.toString(array));` ficando `gravarArq.println(Arrays.toString(array) + "teste");` vai estar um "teste" no final do arquivo, foi assim que percebi que não tá gravando em bin/bytes. Não digo nem por pular as linhas, mas sim por esses valores estarem saindo assim.

Gostaria de saber também como faço para pular linhas e formatar exatamente como no console.

Comment: Bastaria trocar aonde usou System.out.println por `handler.write()` (supondo que esteja usando FileWriter), já que vc montou um método que resolve item a item de um array ao invés de usar Arrays.toString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, tudo bem? Então, basicamente você errou na hora de fazer a impressão do Array para a gravação. Faltou um **for** para percorrer o seu **Array**.

Só foi preciso fazer uma pequena adição, utilizando um código que você mesmo já tinha.

**printMatrix.java**

```
public void matrixToFile(int[][] array, int n) throws IOException{
    FileWriter arqMatrix = new FileWriter("Matriz 1.txt");
    PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arqMatrix);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){  
        gravarArq.println("[");   
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            gravarArq.println(array[i][j]);
        }
        gravarArq.println("]");
    }gravarArq.println("\n"); 

    arqMatrix.close();
    System.out.println("Foi gerado um arquivo 'Matriz 1.txt' no mesmo local do projeto.\n");
}
```

E, como agora estamos passando por parâmetro o valor de **n** é necessário por ele na chamada do método também.

**classePrincipal.java**

```
graph.matrixToFile(matrix1, N);
```

Não fiz todo o trabalho por você, vai ver que a identação no bloco de notas ainda está "errada". Mas essa eu vou deixar pra tu quebrar um pouquinho a cabeça. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Nossa, já ajudou bastante, cara! Agora eu me viro aqui com a formatação haha valeu! Mas ainda fiquei com dúvida do motivo de estar gerando aqueles caracteres aleatorios... Tu saberia me responder?

Comment: Com precisão na fala, não saberia.. Mas meu palpite é que você estava chamando o Array e, por não percorrer ele, recebia como resposta o nome de cada item dentro dele. Como se fosse uma espécie de ID para cada espaço dentro da matriz.

Comment: Ah entendi... De qualquer forma, já resolvi o problema lá xD quem dera se esse fosse o trabalho, eu vou ter que normalizar e fazer as operações dela com threads, vou ter que fazer uma segunda matriz ainda